# SQL is returning an incorrect date

Tags: node.js, mysql-workbench, knex.js

I'm using

- MySQL Workbench
- Node.js with Knex.js

My data in the SQL looks like this:

```
+--------------+----+--------------------+
|     date     | id | happinessIndicator |
+--------------+----+--------------------+
| '2019-10-20' |  1 | happy              |
| '2019-10-20' |  2 | happy              |
| '2019-10-20' |  3 | happy              |
| '2019-10-20' |  4 | happy              |
+--------------+----+--------------------+
```

That's my code to get the votes of the current day

```
exports.day = function (req, res) {
    const today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    knex('votes')
        .where('date', today)
        .then(function (resp) {
            res.json({
                status: true,
                message: 'ok',
                data: resp
            })
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            res.json(
                {
                    status: false,
                    msg: error.code
                }
            )
        })
};
```

but my result looks like this:

[image]

Why doesn't he return `2019-10-20` like there is stored?

Comment: This is just a guess, but it may be a problem with timezones? I imagine, that you store your date without timezone into your database and then, knex tries to get a date with timezone and fails. Since you are probably 2 hours behind GMT, he calculates the date minus those two hours. Try setting the timezone for knex and check if it still happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not an incorrect date, this is `UTC format`.

you can set your own timzone format in your connection object lilke this:
`knex({client,connection,useNullAsDefault: true,timezone: 'UTC',});`